# Replacing Words with Links

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

On my site I have the Catholic Encyclopedia. It has over 11,000 articles.

I'm interested in replacing words and phrases on the articles on my site with links to the relevant entries in the Catholic Encyclopedia. So, if someone says:

> St. Peter was the first pope.

It should replace St. Peter with a link to the article on St. Peter, and pope with a link to the article on the Pope.

I have it working, but it is very slow. There are over 30,000 possible replacements, so it is important to optimize. I'm just not sure where to go from here.

Here's my existing code. Note that it's using Drupal. Also, it replaces the words with a [cathenlink] tag, and that tag is replaced by a real HTML link later in the code.

```
function ce_execute_filter($text)
{

    // If text is empty, return as-is
    if (!$text) {
        return $text;
    }

    // Split by paragraph
    $lines = preg_split('/\n+/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    // Contains the parsed and linked text
    $linked_text = '';

    foreach ($lines as $line)
    {

        // If this fragment is only one or more newline characters,
        // Add it to $linked_text and continue without parsing
        if (preg_match('/^\n+$/', $line)) {
            $linked_text .= $line;
            continue;
        }

        // Select any terms that might be in this line
        // Ordered by descending length of term,
        // so that the longest terms get replaced first
        $result = db_query('SELECT title, term FROM {catholic_encyclopedia_terms} ' .
                "WHERE :text LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(term, '%')) " .
                'GROUP BY term ' .
                'ORDER BY char_length(term) DESC',
                array(
                    ':text' => $line
                    ))
            ->fetchAll();

        // Array with lowercase term as key, title of entry as value
        $terms = array();

        // Array of the terms only in descending order of length
        $ordered_terms = array();

        foreach ($result as $r)
        {
            $terms[strtolower($r->term)] = $r->title;
            $ordered_terms[] = preg_quote($r->term);
        }

        // If no terms were returned, add the line and continue without parsing.
        if (empty($ordered_terms)) {
            $linked_text .= $line;
            continue;
        }

        // Do the replace
        // Get the regexp by joining $ordered_terms with |
        $line = preg_replace_callback('/\b('.
                    implode('|', $ordered_terms) .
                    ')\b/i', function ($matches) use($terms)
                {
                if ($matches[1]) {
                return "[cathenlink=" .
                $terms[strtolower($matches[1])] . "]" .
                $matches[1] . "[/cathenlink]";
                }
                },
                $line);

        $linked_text .= $line;
    }

    return $linked_text;
}
```

I'm doing the preg_replace like this so that it doesn't replace a word twice. I would use strtr, but then there's no way to ensure it is a full word and not just part of a word.

Is there any way to make this faster? Right now it is pretty slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `LIKE` keyword is slowing you down. Is it `indexed`?

You can find some clues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354248/optimizing-mysql-like-string-queries-in-innodb)

Comment: Thanks. Well, I have to use **like** or something similar to narrow down the results, or else it is even slower as it is returning all 30,000+ terms.

Comment: should it be `%whatever%`?, you can optimize it using `%whatever` alone.

Comment: Yes, it has to be %term%, because otherwise the term would have to be in the beginning or the end of the given text, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: you can use the full-text search function. Here's the link for some examples: http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

Comment: The reason I can't really do that is because, well, I'm not searching for text *within* the terms, but searching for terms within given text. The given text itself is not indexed, obviously. The terms are only a few words so are not worth fulltext indexing, and it wouldn't really work that way. The documentation says you can't use a column in the AGAINST function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an indexing system such as Lucene to index the Catholic Encyclopedia.  I don't suspect it changes very often, so indexing can be updated on a daily bassis.  Lucene is written in Java, but I know that Zend has a PHP module that can read the index.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think the way I am doing it is probably the most efficient. What I came up with is to cache the results for one week, so that posts don't have to be parsed more than once per week. Implementing this solution, I've seen a marked improvement in speed on my site, so it seems to be working.

Comment: You could also do some replacements on the fly with JavaScript AJAX calls back to a specific function on your server. That way if you want to update any of those replacements it will work automatically. Save your word replacements/linking info to a table and just return them in an AJAX response to replace it on page.