# MySql `MATCH AGAINST` and `LIKE` combination to search for special characters

Tags: mysql, sql-like, match-against

For example, in database i have row with phrase `DN-NP`.
In input field i type `DN-` and want to find the row.
Here is example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9235a/4
Tried to use `FULLTEXT` index and `MATCH AGAINST`

```
SELECT `name` 
FROM `domains` 
WHERE MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('DN*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

get no results.

Here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/111895/55397 is advice to combine with `LIKE`. At the moment idea is in php something like

```
if( strlen($_POST['input_field_value']) <= 2 ){ 
$sql = 'SELECT `name` 
FROM `domains` 
WHERE MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('DN*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR `name` LIKE "%DN%"'; 
}
```

But LIKE "% %" too slow? Any ideas how to solve the problem (to find phrases that contains special characters)?

What about `LOCATE` (performance)?

```
SELECT name AS name7 
FROM domains 
WHERE LOCATE('DN',`name`)>0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes can help with speed by limiting the number of rows to look at.  Most code shown so far requires testing every row.

- `FULLTEXT` is very good at finding rows *when its rules apply*.  I doubt if `+DN*` applies due to word-length and existence of punctuation.
- `LIKE "DN-NP%" can use an index very efficiently.  But that only works for the string being at the start of the column.
- `LIKE "%DN-NP%" -- The leading wildcard requires checking every row.
- `LOCATE` and any other string operator -- not sargable, so needs to look at every row.
- `REGEXP "DN-NP" -- slower than` LIKE`.  (There are other situations where` REGEXP`can be faster and/or`LIKE` won't apply.)

If you have the min word-length set to 2, then this trick may be the most efficient:

```
WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST("+DN +NP" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND col LIKE '%DN-NP%'
```

The `MATCH` will efficiently whittle down the number of rows; the `LIKE` will make further whittle down the number or rows, but only looking at the small number from the `MATCH`.

Caveat:  Which of these do you need to match or not match?:

```
abc DN-NP def
abc DNs-NPed def   -- look likes "plural", etc which FULLTEXT matches
abc DN-NPQRS def   -- word boundary issue
abc ZYXDN-NP def
```

`REGEXP` can match a "word boundary"; `LIKE` does not have such.

Please build a list of things you want to match / not match.  We might have a better answer for you.

Comment: Thank you for advice. When in input field i type `DN` i want to find in mysql rows that contains ... actually i want to find all rows that contains `DN` in any position (all four examples). If in input field i type `DN-`, i also want to find all mysql rows that contains `DN-` in any position. I mean, i want to find all rows that contain input string(characters)

Comment: Continued tests in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28a3f3/9. Seems with `MATCH` problem is, if in input field i type `-` character, then `IN BOOLEAN MODE` it means `NOT`. Without `BOOLEAN MODE` get nothing. `LIKE` with `%...%` does exactly what i need. But as i understand is too slow if many rows. So question is how to decrease number of rows for `LIKE`. Interesting information here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41716705/2118559 "I would like to comment that surprisingly, creating an index also helped speed up queries for like '%abc%' queries in my case."

Comment: @Andris - `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_ft_min_token_size';` probably says 3, which means that `DN` is too short to be indexed.

Comment: Yes, correct, minimum is 3. Got     `[0] => Array         (             [Variable_name] => innodb_ft_min_token_size             [Value] => 3         )`

Comment: @Andris - If you change that setting to 2, you will need to recreate the index before it takes effect.

Answer (score 1):

how about regexp ?

SELECT name AS name6
FROM domains
WHERE `name` regexp ('DN');